# Can I return an edited object back to Controller from my strongly-typed View without having to use Request.Form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Just wondering, I strongly type these views in ASP.NET MVC and then use Request.Form on the submit controller to get the data out, validate it, put it in an object, send to database. Is there a way I can just send the object back from the View page since it is strongly typed instead of doing all this crap to just end up with an object again since I just started with one anyways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean, model binding?

```
[AcceptVerbs (HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult UpdateUser (User user)
{            
    SaveUpdates ();

    return View();
}
```

This will automatically initialize the User properties with the form values with the same names.

Look at this answer: [ASP.Net MVC Custom Model Binding explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193453/asp-net-mvc-custom-model-binding-explanation/1249602#1249602)

[image]
<sub>(source: [odetocode.com](http://www.odetocode.com/aimages/200904/magicmodelbinder_3.jpg))</sub>

Comment: ASP.NET MVC uses the ModelBinder object to bind your form elements to your model.  If you're using the DefaultModelBinder (and most folks do), then simply give your form elements the same name as your model's properties.  Keep in mind that ModelBinder can only bind to properties and not fields.  HTH

Comment: @JM - what do you mean, and not fields? By bind to properties you mean that you can bind request input values to properties of your model object right?

Comment: Properties are different from fields.  Properties have getters & setters where fields don't.  Most primitive models will just use auto-properties, I just didn't want you to get wrapped around the axle by trying to bind to fields.  And, yes, ModelBinder will bind the values of form elements to model properties of the same name.