# Web API hide field from consumer of service

Tags: c#, web-services, model, asp.net-web-api

I have a class - `Person`. The consumer of the Web API service must set the ID. I **don't** want them to be able to set or even see the InternalID.

```
public class Person
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ID is required.")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string InternalID { get; set; }

 }
```

Other parts of my application will need to work with the InternalID, so setting it private/internal won't work.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851207/prevent-property-from-being-serialized-in-web-api

Comment: That post suggests many approaches and has many links to external articles. Is there one in particular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found this and it looks good to me.

```
    [JsonIgnore]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string InternalID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you obfuscate your id? You could have a function crypting the ID to a value and then de-crypting it. So the encrypted ID would be public and the decrypted ID would be private.

Comment: Seems a bit heavy when all I want to make sure I have a unique ID.