# Limit returned JSON child depth in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, asp.net-web-api

I'm create a RESTful API using ASP.NET Web API. I am trying to work out the best way of limiting the amount of data child objects show.

To explain, I have three entities, Objects, Channels and ChannelData. An object can have 0 or more Channels and a Channel can have 0 or more ChannelData (and usually 1000s).

I want the following endpoints:

- `/api/Objects`

  - Returns the JSON list of objects and their channels but **not** the ChannelData (maybe summary data instead e.g. the amount of data etc).
- `/api/Objects/{{objectId}}/ChannelData?channel={{channelName}}`

  - Returns all the data in JSON for a particular channel for a particular object.

By default, Web API tries to show everything in /api/Objects including 1000s of ChannelData objects. What is the best way of preventing the array of ChannelData from appearing for a specific endpoint?

Comment: Web API only shows what you return in the method. So, don't load channeldata?

Comment: Are you using an ORM? Can you post the code for your `GET` method?

Comment: Object contains a list of Channels which contain a list of ChannelData. If I return an Object it will automatically include the Channels list and the ChannelData list.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the best way to achieve this is to "not load the data"; you can also consider to change the response of you method with a different model.

Anyway, if you can't do anything of that, you can try using this tag `[JsonIgnore]` on ChannelData property (or `[IgnoreDataMember]` if you use the xml formatter); the serialization engine will skip that property during response generation.

Check [this](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size) article or [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization) article for more details or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851207/prevent-property-from-being-serialized-in-web-api) SO answer.