# .Net Core WebAPI connection reset, when I have "include" in my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a new project with .Net Core. It's a WebAPI project. And I have a separate project for my model.

In WebAPI project, in a controller, I have something like this:

```
    // GET: api/questions
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Question> GetQuestions()
    {
        return _context.Questions
            .Include( i => i.QuestionType );
    }
```

When I call `http://localhost:55555/api/questios/` it just returns the first record, and then this error message:
     Recv failure: Connection was reset

If I remove the `Include` part and just return the `_context.Questions`, it work just fine!

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Is LazyLoading enabled? Maybe you can just flat the entities to a List<T> object in order to understand the reason.

Comment: To debug this, wrap the return in a try/catch and then add .ToList() after the .Include

Comment: How do you inject your context in your controller ? By the DI service ?

Comment: @ali Lazy Loading is still not available in EF Core

Comment: Take a look to this issue, it can be the same error : https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5910

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found the answer. Thank you everyone who helped.

I added json options according to [Loading related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

> If you are using ASP.NET Core, you can configure Json.NET to ignore cycles that it finds in the object graph. This is done in the ConfigureServices(...) method in Startup.cs.

```
            services.AddMvc()
              .AddJsonOptions(
                    options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling
                        = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore );
```

Comment: I found this solved my problem, but then I found another way which I think I prefer. I added the `[JsonIgnore]` decorator to the properties that I didn't want to serialize and there were no longer any loops to worry about. I suspect this is usually the reference from a child back to its parent. See this answer for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11851461/5322405

Comment: Awesome addition, @KenLyon. I'm not yet sure this is my exact problem here, but I've been using `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` and much prefer the decorator solution.

Comment: Ah! I discovered that I did, in fact, have `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` set in `services.AddMvc()`, but because I had added `JsonSerializerSettings` in a _specific_ Json() call, it was being overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// GET: api/questions
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Question> GetQuestions()
{
    var res = _context.Questions
        .Include( i => i.QuestionType ).ToArray();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: It's the same as before.

Comment: Can you Include other related entities? Or do you get the same error for everything you include?

Comment: I have updated the code. Try and debug this with a break point to watch the "res" variable.