# Web api return only some fields

Tags: c#, webapi

Following api function returns PartnerApiModel object, which is good.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
   PartnerAPIModel apiPartner = new PartnerAPIModel();
   apiPartner.PublicId = "1";
   apiPartner.DisplayName = "Show this";
   apiPartner.Name = "Test";

   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, apiPartner);
}
```

The result:

```
{
    "PublicId": "7eda5b39-7ef8-ea29-6136-37701e05b0cc",
    "DisplayName": "Show this",
    "Name": "Test",
}
```

Is it possible to return only following?

```
{
    "PublicId": "7eda5b39-7ef8-ea29-6136-37701e05b0cc",
    "DisplayName": "Show this",
}
```

Comment: Yes, Show us `PartnerAPIModel ` model

Comment: You can create another model/dto which will contain only needed fields. Or use `JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues` or `NullValueHandling.Ignore`(depends in underlying json serializer) and don't set `Name`. Or mark property with corresponding  `Ignore` attribute. Depends on concrete use-case.

Comment: Remove the `Name` property from `PartnerAPIModel`?

Comment: Does this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851207/prevent-property-from-being-serialized-in-web-api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prevent property from being serialized in web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851207/prevent-property-from-being-serialized-in-web-api)

Comment: Why set the `Name` if you don't want it returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark the propertie who you want to ignore with jsonIgnore:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public class PartnerApiModel {
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```