# C# Web Api rest linq query return too much data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Good day,
I run into the problem then returning DTO object.
I have these classes

```
public class ProductBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductVariant> Variants { get; set; }
    public int BaseImageId { get; set; } = 0;

}

public class ProductVariant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int ProductBaseId { get; set; }
    public ProductBase productBase { get; set; }
    public int ProductSizeId { get; set; }
    public ProductSize ProductSize { get; set; }
    public int ProductColorId { get; set; }
    public ProductColor ProductColor { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ImageVariant> imageVariants { get; set; }
}

public class ProductColor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductVariant> productVariant { get; set; }
}

public class ProductSize
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ProductVariant> productVariant { get; set; }
}
```

In productBaseRepository I have this call

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Models.ProductBase>> GetAllWithVariantsAsync()
    {
        var result = await _dataContext.ProductBases
            .Include(pb => pb.Variants)
            .ThenInclude(v => v.ProductSize)
            .Include(pb => pb.Variants)
            .ThenInclude(v => v.ProductColor)
            .ToListAsync();

        return result;
    }
```

I have created DTO convertion function

```
public static IEnumerable<ProductBaseDTO> ConvertToDto(this IEnumerable<ProductBase> productBases)
    {
        var returnProductBaseDto = (from product in productBases
                                    select new ProductBaseDTO
                                    {
                                        Id = product.Id,
                                        Name = product.Name,
                                        Variants = product.Variants.ToList(),
                                        Description = product.Description,
                                        BaseImageId = product.BaseImageId,
                                        
                                    }).ToList();
        
        return returnProductBaseDto;
    }
```

But then I call this function from swagger

```
 [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<ProductBaseDTO>>> GetAllProductsWithVariants()
    {
        var baseProductDomain = await _productBaseRepository.GetAllWithVariantsAsync();
        var baseProduct = baseProductDomain.ConvertToDto();
        return Ok(baseProduct);
    }
```

I get that
System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32

If I remove variants from call it works, so I need to some how remove Unecessry values from Variants

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens because your `ProductVariant` references `ProductSize` and `ProductColor` and `ProductSize` and `ProductColor` reference a list of `ProductVariant` objects. And `ProductVariant` has a reference to its `BaseProduct`. This creates a cycle, two objects referencing each other.

In order to solve this issue, remove `productVariant` List from `ProductSize` and `ProductColor` or remove the `ProductSize` and `ProductColor` references from `ProductVariant`. Also remove the `productBase` reference from `ProductVariant`.

Use the IDs to find object references if required instead of having circular object references.

See [prevent property from being serialized in web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851207/prevent-property-from-being-serialized-in-web-api) on how to prevent properties from being serialized without removing the property declaration from the class.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Variants` has a reference to its parents type,
You could simply set this to null, e.g.

`foreach(var x in baseProduct.SelectMany(c => c.Variants) { x.ProductBase = null }`

We ussually have different viewmodels to stop these cycles, e.g:

```cs
public class Order {
  public List<OrderLine> OrderLines {get;set}
}

public class OrderLine {
  public Order Order {get;set}
}

// Gets mapped to the following viewmodels:

public class OrderViewModel {
  public List<OrderOrderLineViewModel > OrderLines {get;set}
}

public class OrderOrderLineViewModel {
  public Order Order => null; // Stop object cycling
}
```

Note that the exception message should tell you where the issue is for example `$.Variants.productBase.variants.productBase.variants` or something similar.