# ASP MVC Model Binding of DropDown fail

Tags: entity-framework

I have ASP MVC 4 project.
I have problem that when I try to create new Survey the code in the controller also fail to bind the posted form data to the model.

The specific error is:

> The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'DNASurvey.Models.Tenant' failed because no type converter can convert between these types. {System.InvalidOperationException}

Those are the models I have:

```
public class Tenant {
    [Key]
    public string TenantID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Survey> Surveys { get; set; }
  }

  public class Survey {
    [Key]
    public string SurveyID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength=5)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public uint CurrentRoundIndex { get; set; }
  }
```

I also have SurveyController with this relavant code:

```
public ActionResult Create() {
  AddPossibleTenants();
  return View();
}

//
// POST: /Survey/Create

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Survey survey) {
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    survey.SurveyID = EncodeNameToSingleString(survey.Title);
    db.Surveys.Add(survey);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }

  AddPossibleTenants();
  return View(survey);
}

private void AddPossibleTenants() {
  ViewBag.PossibleTenants = db.Tenants.ToList();
}
```

And this view for create:

```
@model DNASurvey.Models.Survey

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Survey</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tenant)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Tenant, new SelectList(ViewBag.PossibleTenants, "TenantID", "Name"))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tenant)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedAt)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedAt)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedAt)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is generating a select element for Tenant, which will pass back a simple name-value pair. This won't bind to the Tenant property of your model, because Tenant is defined in your model as an object, not a string. You'll need to define your own [custom model-binder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193453/asp-net-mvc-custom-model-binding-explanation) to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this series of posts about EF and MVC](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/28/mvcscaffolding-one-to-many-relationships/).
[This post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/28/mvcscaffolding-one-to-many-relationships/) explain how to use the scaffold command to create controllers and how to build the model so both EF and MVC will work right.