# Decimal numbers in ASP.NET MVC 5 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with decimal numbers.

If I use .(dot) instead of ,(comma) in the textbox it comes null in controller.

I know its a language issue because in spanish we use comma instead of dot for decimals but I need to use dot.

It is possible to change this?

It is strange because in controller I have to use .(dot) for decimals i.e:

I can do `float x = 3.14` but I can not do `float x = 3,14` so I do not understand this... In some cases I have to use dot... In others I have to use comma...

This is my code:

**In model:**

```
[Display(Name = "Total")]
public double Total { get; set; }
```

**In view:**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Total, new { id = "Total", htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control" } })
```

**In controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Codigo,Fecha,Trabajo,Notas,BaseImponible,Iva,Total,Verificado,FormaDePagoID,ClienteID")] Presupuesto presupuesto)
    {
```

Comment: If this is ASP.NET MVC, the correct tag would be `asp.net-mvc` (the descriptions should make this clear if you read them)

Answer (score 7):

Thanks everybody. I found this [code from Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/) that works pretty well.

Create a class in any folder of your project

```
public class ModelBinder
{
    public class DecimalModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                                         ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            object result = null;

            // Don't do this here!
            // It might do bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError
            // and there is no RemoveModelError!
            // 
            // result = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

            string modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
            string attemptedValue =
                bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName).AttemptedValue;

            // Depending on CultureInfo, the NumberDecimalSeparator can be "," or "."
            // Both "." and "," should be accepted, but aren't.
            string wantedSeperator = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator;
            string alternateSeperator = (wantedSeperator == "," ? "." : ",");

            if (attemptedValue.IndexOf(wantedSeperator) == -1
                && attemptedValue.IndexOf(alternateSeperator) != -1)
            {
                attemptedValue =
                    attemptedValue.Replace(alternateSeperator, wantedSeperator);
            }

            try
            {
                if (bindingContext.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType
                    && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attemptedValue))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                result = decimal.Parse(attemptedValue, NumberStyles.Any);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(modelName, e);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Add this to Application_Start() method in Global.asax

```
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new ModelBinder.DecimalModelBinder());
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal?), new ModelBinder.DecimalModelBinder());
```

Now use decimal type instead of float or double and everything will go fine !!
Thank you mates see you around !.

Comment: Can you do it the same and still use double?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller uses C#. The language specific states that `.` is the decimal separator. Period. It's not language specific, that's just it.

Your database or UI (which uses the server's language settings) might use another decimal separator than the default (US) language setting C# uses. That's why you have to use `,` as separator there.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to use a custom model binder.

See this blog post http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

If you want your comma(,) separated decimal input in UI as per UI culture, to be converted to dot(.) to bind to C# decimal number, you can go for Asp.Net MVC's custom model binder, where take the comma separated decimal string and replace the comma with a dot and then assign to the C# decimal property.

The advantage is, its reusable across the application, where you might be having recurring scenarios for decimal conversions.

Hope following links could help you:

[ASP.Net MVC Custom Model Binding explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193453/asp-net-mvc-custom-model-binding-explanation)
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/