# How to trim spaces from some POST'ed Form Data that is backed by a .NET EmailAddress DataAnnotation

Tags: c#, .net, validation, data-annotations

I have a simple Input Model that has an `Email` property on it. I'm using the `EmailAddress` DataAnnotation to validate the input data.

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "UserReview_CustomerEmailTitle", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.User.Settings))]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.User.Settings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserReview_InvalidEmailMessage")]
public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
```

It works perfectly (ie. data is valid) if there are no spaces before/after the input data.

When I have a space at the end of the input text, it fails the validation.

Is there any tricks I can do to TRIM the input data coming in OR tell the EmailAddress validator to ignore prepended/postpended spaces?

#### EDIT:

I'm open to creating a custom attribute... I can't inherit from the `EmailAddress` attribute because it's `sealed` (sigh) .. so maybe a regex attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could handle in javascript when user tabs out of the email field to run [trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) on the value and replace it.  EmailAddress annotation plays nice with [unobtrusive validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/email) on the client side (assuming MVC here).

If you want to avoid client side, you might look into a custom model binder where you could manipulate the data used to create the model-to-be-validated.  You could check out some tutorials [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193453/asp-net-mvc-custom-model-binding-explanation).

Last but not least, maybe you could [borrow the regex used within the Email validator](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Web.Mvc/EmailAddressAttribute.cs) and make it accept whitespace via a new [RegularExpression validator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and handle the TRIM in your code explicitly.

Comment: Can't do client side manipulation unfortunately. Server side is safest.

Comment: The regex solution could be the easiest right now ... any link to that?

Comment: as in .. any link to the email _regex_ pattern... :) (i know about the attribute)

Comment: @Pure.Krome it is a nice one :)  [github!](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Web.Mvc/EmailAddressAttribute.cs)  ... no idea why but the [coreFX one](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs/#L19) is rather lame..

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to make changes to the model, you could add another property and validate it:

```
[Required]
public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }

[Required]
[Display(Name = "UserReview_CustomerEmailTitle", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.User.Settings))]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.User.Settings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserReview_InvalidEmailMessage")]
public string CustomerEmailTrimmed => CustomerEmail?.Trim();
```

Had a similar problem on ASP.NET Core 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try `CustomerEmail.Trim()`. It does exactly what you describe.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Use it to TRIM the input data coming :)

Comment: @KelvinLai that isnt how DataAnnotations work...not quite that simple.  You could go crazy with a model binder (assuming MVC)... but i would not recommend that.